# Htaccess Redirect To Custom Permalinks from Blogspot to Wordpress

Tags: redirect, migration, blogspot

I move from Blogspot to Wordpress.

Blogspot url

`domain*com/year/month/post-name.html`

Wordpress Set Custom Permalink

```
domain*com/%author%/%postname%/
```

I use this redirection on .htaccess

```
RedirectMatch 301 /([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)\.html$ /$3/
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^m=1$
RewriteRule (.*) $1? [R=permanent]
```

Its only redirect to `domain*com/%postname%/`

How to redirect url to `domain*com/%author%/%postname%/`